# $count in between dates and $group by field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is a sample, where `processes`, `processCompletedBy`, and `processCompletedTime` are stored.
The goal is to determine the performance of each employee and his completed processes which should range between two dates.

```
[
    {
        processA: {
            processCompletedBy: "001",
            processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-03T7:23:57.701Z"),
        },
        processB: {
            processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-05T6:47:57.701Z"),
            processCompletedBy: "002",
        },
        processC: {
            processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-05T4:47:57.701Z"),
            processCompletedBy: "003"
        }
    },
    {
        processA: {
            processCompletedBy: "003",
            processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-05T00:47:57.701Z"),
        },
        processB: {
            processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-06T00:47:57.701Z"),
            processCompletedBy: "001",
        },
        processC: {
            processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-05T00:47:57.701Z"),
            processCompletedBy: "002"
        }
    },
    {
        processA: {
            processCompletedBy: "002",
            processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-07T00:47:57.701Z"),
        },
        processB: {
            processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-06T00:47:57.701Z"),
            processCompletedBy: "003",
        },
        processC: {
            processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-08T00:47:57.701Z"),
            processCompletedBy: "001"
        }
    }
]
```

For expected output, the date range is from "2023-09-03" to "2023-09-08". It should exclude the process that doesn't match the date range criteria.

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        processCompletedBy: "001",
        countOfProcesses: 3, //The no of activity done by him
        summary: [
            {
                process: "processA",
                processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-03T7:23:57.701Z"),
            },
            {
                process: "processB",
                processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-06T00:47:57.701Z"),
            },
            {
                process: "processC",
                processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-08T00:47:57.701Z"),
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        processCompletedBy: "002",
        countOfProcesses: 3,
        summary: [
            {
                process: "processB",
                processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-05T6:47:57.701Z"),
            },
            {
                process: "processC",
                processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-05T00:47:57.701Z"),
            },
            {
                process: "processA",
                processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-07T00:47:57.701Z"),
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        processCompletedBy: "003",
        countOfProcesses: 3,
        summary: [
            {
                process: "processC",
                processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-05T4:47:57.701Z"),
            },
            {
                process: "processA",
                processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-06T00:47:57.701Z"),
            },
            {
                process: "processB",
                processCompletedTime: ISODate("2023-09-07T00:47:57.701Z"),
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Correct me if my effort to make this problem understandable is not up to mark.

Comment: Would say you should redesign your data structure. I don't see any reason that you should place processA, processB and processC into the same document. This makes the query even complex and poor in performance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried to categorize each process in project stage and group them...but didn't help..don't know how to approach for the solution

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, the document schema design is poor. This requires you to have at least 3 stages in order to convert the documents into the (ideal document) format that makes it easy to query.

And you should be concerned about the *extensibility* of the document, for example if there are "processD", "processE" and so on, you have to modify the query again and this makes the query performance worse.

The ideal document schema should be like:

```
{
  "type": "processA",
  "process": "dishwashing",
  "processCompletedBy": "001",
  "processCompletedTime": ISODate("2023-09-07T00:47:57.701Z")
}
```

Once you are able to convert the document into the ideal document format, this makes everything, just a simple filter document via `$match`, group the documents for performing the count, and add objects into the `summary` array via `$group`.

Also, I don't see any reason that you should consider that applying the dynamic key like "processA", "processB" will be the key in the output document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      A: {
        processName: "processA",
        process: "$processA",
        processCompletedTime: "$processACompletedTime",
        processCompletedBy: "$processACompletedBy"
      },
      B: {
        processName: "processB",
        process: "$processB",
        processCompletedTime: "$processBCompletedTime",
        processCompletedBy: "$processBCompletedBy"
      },
      C: {
        processName: "processC",
        process: "$processC",
        processCompletedTime: "$processCCompletedTime",
        processCompletedBy: "$processCCompletedBy"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        processes: {
          $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$processes"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$processes.v"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      processCompletedTime: {
        $gte: ISODate("2023-09-03"),
        $lte: ISODate("2023-09-08")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$processCompletedBy",
      countOfProcesses: {
        $count: {}
      },
      summary: {
        $push: {
          process: [
            {
              k: "$processName",
              v: "$process"
            }
          ],
          processCompletedTime: "$processCompletedTime"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      processCompletedBy: "$_id",
      countOfProcesses: "$countOfProcesses",
      summary: {
        $map: {
          input: "$summary",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                $arrayToObject: "$$this.process"
              },
              {
                processCompletedTime: "$$this.processCompletedTime"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XOM0lrJhrj_)

Comment: can you please share some tips how one can measure their problem solving skill and develop problem solving approach?  because I get stuck for every simple problem.

Comment: It's all about analyzing the problem, doing research, finding and implementing the solution, you may make mistakes (but don't be scared), learning from it, and repeating. Of course, this is a long process/journey for mastering this skill. Would say that I am also not a master and still learning it to improve my analytical and explaining skills. Ya, the best way to improve your skill is more practice & attempt, and don't hesitate to ask the question. Good luck. =D